# /usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib64/libm.so'

Tags: linux, gcc, build, redhat

I'm not experienced at building with gcc at all and now require some help.
I've a code that is being built with the following options

```
gcc \
    -g myCode.C \
    -O \
    -o myCode \
    -I. \
    -L. \
    -L/usr/lib64 \
    -lstdc++ \
    -Wreturn-type \
    -Wswitch \
    -Wcomment \
    -Wformat \
    -Wchar-subscripts \
    -Wparentheses \
    -Wpointer-arith \
    -Wcast-qual \
    -Woverloaded-virtual \
    -Wno-write-strings /usr/lib64/libm.so \
    -Wno-deprecated
```

When compiling `myCode.C` on redhat 6 machine it is not working on older versions of the OS throwing errors

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found
```

To fix this issue, I've tried to add `-static` build option to make all dynamic linking libraries as static, but have some build error which i dont understand :(

```
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib64/libm.so'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I make my code to work on older version of redhat rather than only on 6 and newer ?? what build options should I add/remove ?

Comment: remove  `/usr/lib64/libm.so`  from `-Wno-write-strings /usr/lib64/libm.so` and add `-lm` instead if necessary.

Comment: @ymonad `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm`

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/lib64/libm.so` is a dynamic library. Since you link explicitly with it, `-static` doesn't force using the static version (`libm.a`)
You are trying to compile a C++ program so you should use g++. Passing the `libstdc++` and `libm` libraries is not needed then. Also `/usr/lib64` should be in your standard link path so is not needed.

So you should use:

```
g++ \
    -static \
    -g myCode.C \
    -O \
    -o myCode \
    -I. \
    -L. \
    -Wreturn-type \
    -Wswitch \
    -Wcomment \
    -Wformat \
    -Wchar-subscripts \
    -Wparentheses \
    -Wpointer-arith \
    -Wcast-qual \
    -Woverloaded-virtual \
    -Wno-write-strings \
    -Wno-deprecated
```